# Jupyter kernel Apache toree startup timeout

Tags: apache-toree

I installed toree with the following command in my Ubuntu 16.04 system:

```
$ pip install --pre toree

$ jupyter toree install --interpreters=Scala,PySpark,SQL
```

Then I checked the kernel list. I got kernels installed succussfully:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
  python3                 /home/ypdx/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  apache_toree_pyspark    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_pyspark
  apache_toree_scala      /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala
  apache_toree_sql        /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_sql
```

Then I start jupyter, here comes the question: Both apache_toree_scala and apache_toree_pyspark kernel will run in error "timeout" when I create a new notebook using that kernel. Here is the error message:

```
Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from d98705f0-4bba-4c69-af7f-da99379219f5
```

My ubuntu was installed in VirtualBox. But I think this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Did you set SPARK_HOME variable before installing toree kernels?

Comment: can you add the log output once you start jupyter